# CSS stack angular repeats horizontal not vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat but for every div it creates it stacks them vertically. For this page, I am scrolling horizontally so is it possible to have these horizontal instead so they are all side by side as far as possible?

Here is the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in rooms">
               <div class="display:inline-block">
                      <div class="item item-icon" style="margin-bottom:10px !important;width:400px;">

                         <div><span class="icon ion-home"></span> <b>New Room</b></div>
                         <label class="item item-input">
                         <span class="input-label">Name</span><textarea placeholder="" ng-model="r.name"> </textarea>
                         </label>
                         <label class="item item-input">
                         <span class="input-label">Floor</span><textarea placeholder="Eg Ground Floor" ng-model="r.room"> </textarea>
                         </label>
                         <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                         <span class="input-label">Description</span>
                         <textarea placeholder="yyy" rows="8" cols="10" ng-model="r.description">
                         </textarea>
                         </label>
                         <button class="button button-full button-dark" ng-click="startRoomProfileUpload(1,$index)">
                         Add An Image
                         </button>
                         <button class="button button-full button-dark" ng-click="removeRoom(r)">
                         Remove Room
                         </button>
                         <div class="row">
                            <span ng-repeat="x in r.selectedImageUri">
                               <div style="width:100%;">
                                  <div class="col">
                                     <img ng-src="{{x}}" width="100%" style="max-width:200px;" alt="image" style="">
                                     <div><button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="removeImage(r.selectedImageUri)" style="width:100%;">Delete</button></div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </span>
                         </div>
                      </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Mistake in your code replace <div class="display:inline-block"> with <div style="display:inline-block">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `float:left` to your `<div ng-repeat="r in rooms">` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add css to `<div class="row">`: `display:table`

and for `<span ng-repeat="x in r.selectedImageUri">`: `display:table-column`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to repeat elements horizontally with the parent element adjusting it's width to automatically fit the children?

If that is the case try this.

Set parent element to have `overflow-x:scroll; white-space: nowrap;` and child elements to have `display:inline-block;`

View working here: https://jsfiddle.net/Collins/8s5fqmez/